# query SUM function issue/ grouping issue

Tags: sql-server, sum

I am running into an issue where using the Sum() function is not working as it should be. I am running this query.

```
SELECT        tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, 
              tServiceHours.JobCode, 
              tServiceReports.[Date], 
              tServiceHours.[Hours]
FROM          AdjustUserRoleRequestStatusLookup 
CROSS JOIN    tServiceJobCodes 
INNER JOIN    tServiceHours 
ON            tServiceJobCodes.ServiceJobCodes = tServiceHours.JobCode 
INNER JOIN    tServiceReports 
ON            tServiceHours.ReportNo = tServiceReports.ReportNo 
INNER JOIN    tServiceReps 
ON            tservicereports.employee = tservicereps.repid 
INNER JOIN    tRegions 
ON            tServiceReports.Region = tRegions.RegionCode
where         Date between '2017-10-03' and '2017-10-03'
and           EmployeeNumber = '10245'
GROUP BY      tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, 
              tServiceHours.JobCode, 
              tServiceReports.[Date], 
              tServiceHours.[Hours]
order by      EmployeeNumber asc
```

Gives the below output

```
EmployeeNumber  JobCode                 Date           Hours
10245             82         2017-10-03 00:00:00.000    0.50
10245             82         2017-10-03 00:00:00.000    1.50
10245            215         2017-10-03 00:00:00.000    2.50
10245            215         2017-10-03 00:00:00.000    3.00
```

When I add the sum() to hours I get weird results back.

```
SELECT        tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, 
              tServiceHours.JobCode, 
              tServiceReports.[Date], 
              sum(tServiceHours.Hours) as Hourz
FROM          AdjustUserRoleRequestStatusLookup 
CROSS JOIN    tServiceJobCodes 
INNER JOIN    tServiceHours 
ON            tServiceJobCodes.ServiceJobCodes = tServiceHours.JobCode 
INNER JOIN    tServiceReports 
ON            tServiceHours.ReportNo = tServiceReports.ReportNo 
INNER JOIN    tServiceReps 
ON            tservicereports.employee = tservicereps.repid 
INNER JOIN    tRegions 
ON            tServiceReports.Region = tRegions.RegionCode
where         Date between '2017-10-03' and '2017-10-03'
and           EmployeeNumber = '10245'
GROUP BY      tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, 
              tServiceHours.JobCode, 
              tServiceReports.[Date], 
              tServiceHours.[Hours]
order by      EmployeeNumber asc
```

I get the below faulty output

```
EmployeeNumber  JobCode            Date          Hourz
10245             82    2017-10-03 00:00:00.000  17.50
10245            215    2017-10-03 00:00:00.000  27.50
```

from what I gather, the grouping is not working properly, which is probably what is causing the Sum() to go haywire. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Comment: Change the GROU BY clause to be just `GROUP BY  tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, tServiceHours.JobCode, tServiceReports.[Date]`

Comment: McNets, whats RDBMS? Sorry new to the forum.

Comment: @joshuaortiz the DataBase Management System that you use (Oracle, Postgres, Firebird, DB2, Sybase, SQLite, ...). There are so many. It's probably SQL Server or Sybase, judging from the use of square brackets but we can't be sure. Please also add the version of it.

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ , it is ms sql. sorry for not including it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your main query as a subquery:

```
SELECT EmployeeNumber,
       JobCode,
       [Date],
       SUM(Hours) as [Hours]
FROM
(
SELECT        tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, 
              tServiceHours.JobCode, 
              tServiceReports.[Date], 
              tServiceHours.[Hours]
FROM          AdjustUserRoleRequestStatusLookup 
CROSS JOIN    tServiceJobCodes 
INNER JOIN    tServiceHours 
ON            tServiceJobCodes.ServiceJobCodes = tServiceHours.JobCode 
INNER JOIN    tServiceReports 
ON            tServiceHours.ReportNo = tServiceReports.ReportNo 
INNER JOIN    tServiceReps 
ON            tservicereports.employee = tservicereps.repid 
INNER JOIN    tRegions 
ON            tServiceReports.Region = tRegions.RegionCode
where         Date between '2017-10-03' and '2017-10-03'
and           EmployeeNumber = '10245'
GROUP BY      tServiceReps.EmployeeNumber, 
              tServiceHours.JobCode, 
              tServiceReports.[Date], 
              tServiceHours.[Hours]
) ctHours
GROUP BY EmployeeNumber, JobCode, [Date];
```

Comment: You can't have an order by in a CTE without a TOP, drunky ;)

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik yep, it's true,

Comment: yep, I am half asleep and want to go back on Holiday! thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: @McNets is there a way to have it return all null values for hours? for example:
where hours LIKE '%' +@hours+ '%

Comment: I' m sorry but I don t understand, is there any group where sum() will return  null?